# How to connect through XMPP in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

Since there's no tutorials and no frameworks on XMPP in Swift yet, I guess I'll be the first to ask... how do you connect to your XMPP server in Swift?

I'm really lost here and would appreciate any comments. It would be very helpful.

Update: Using these 2 tutorials to use the Obj-C XMPPFramework in Swift, and after adding paths, I've come across an error message when trying to import the dependencies.

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

```
'DDXML.h' file not found
```

Comment: Use the Obj-C XMPP framework.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I get an error `:0: error: opening import file 'Swift.swift': Not a directory`. Added these details to the question.

Comment: You're not doing it right. Post more details. How are you adding the framework? How are you importing things?

Comment: To import XMPP, I dragged in the framework folder. I built a bridge and added that in the settings, just like the tutorial I linked. Where did this error come from? What setting does `Swift.swift` rely on?

Comment: What is Swift.swift?

Comment: Absolutely no idea. It just appeared after changing paths. So I reset them to default and set them again, and that error went away. Now I'm getting an error: `"DDXML.h" file not found`, even though KissXML is bundled with XMPPFramework.

Comment: Swift.swift error (I can see the name of your project is Swift). The error above occurs if the swift part of your project has an error, so it dont compile the swift part and the objective-c part get the error mentioned because it cant import what wasn't compiled in the first place.

Comment: @User did you found the solution to the problem?

Comment: any solution here?